# How to pass a dynamic format to a C# 6 interpolated string

Tags: c#, string-formatting, string-interpolation, c#-6.0

I know I can use `$"{value:format}"` to use a specific format that is known at compile time (Like `$"{value:D}"`)

But how can I do this using a dynamic format that is only known at runtime?

I've tried this:

```
public string PrintFormat(decimal value, string customFormat)
{
    return $"Your value is {value:customFormat}";
}
```

But using the above method, I expect that `PrintFormat(123.456m, "D") == "123"`.
But it always returns `"customFormat"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, but you can do this instead:

```
return $"Your value is {value.ToString(customFormat)}";
```